Reproducing and stopping sounds from Python
I was interested in creating a script that could play songs as threads and be able to stop it and reproduce other sounds. I have seen that there's a module for reproducing sounds playsound3, but it is based on threads, and doesn't have this feature.
Seeing threading package made me understand that threads can't be interrupted once they have started.
I am looking for some advice if you know if there is any module that has this feature, or any tips in how to deal with this problem. I have seen that using processes instead of threads could help, but I did a small script using this and the sounds would just overlap.
Thanks

Deleting the thread before creating the new one.
Using processes that includes the thread inside of it.

Edit 1: The idea was to create a script that works as a mp3 player. I would like to have control of which track is sounding, and be able to stop it, change to other sound, and start reproducing it.
I tried using playsound3 and multiprocessing using this script:
from playsound3 import playsound
import multiprocessing
import time

def reproduce_song(mp3_file):
    playsound(mp3_file, block = False)

def main():
    mp3_file = "raze.mp3"
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=reproduce_song, args=(mp3_file,))
    process.start()

    time.sleep(1)

    process.terminate()
    mp3_file = "raze-ultimate.mp3"
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=reproduce_song, args=(mp3_file,))
    process.start()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Also, this is the main abstract of playsound3 where the sound is reproduced:
    if block:
        _play(path)
    else:
        Thread(target=_play, args=(path,), daemon=True).start()

I have tried to modify this fragment assigning the thread to a variable and returning it, but when it returns to the main script, the variable isn't defined despite the audio still being reproduced. It shouldn't finish the thread until all the sound is reproduced, right? I suppose I could debug it from the playsound3 module?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

How can I get this question again to the top in order to get answered? I had no reply at the end by the user who tried to answer it. I think deleting this question and redoing it shouldn't be the best way.

This is generally bad practice however, you can kill the thread that a process is running on. In your case, you can play your sound on a thread and then kill the thread that the sound was being played on which will cause the audio to stop.
Alternatively, you can try the multiprocessing library which will let you play your audio on a background process and let you terminate the process at will.
It would be helpful if you provided the code that you tried.
multiprocessing library docs can be found here

Hello @AryaanSheth, thanks for the answer! I know it is a bad practice but which would be the alternative? This is a project I want to develop, maybe I could extend a bit on an edit when I have some spare time. I have tried ``multiprocessingbut perhaps I did it incorrectly. I encapsulated the thread into a process, and used the methodterminate` but it wasn't the expected behaviour. I will edit my post with the code asap!

I had updated the post with the code I used
